# How to detect Node at specific point without using deprecated `pickNode(double, double)`

Tags: java, javafx

I read a number of post dealing with the issue of "detect Node at specific point"  (like: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354408/how-to-detect-node-at-specific-point-in-javafx), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420569/javafx-2-2-get-node-at-coordinates-visual-tree-hit-testing)  and more).
[Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14421996/3992939) include code that makes use of the [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/deprecated-list.html) `impl_pickNode(double, double)`.
Is there a valid alternative in javafx API, or should I use a custom method like this [one](http://fxexperience.com/2016/01/node-picking-in-javafx/) ?.

Comment: Java is open source. Maybe you can just copy the code into your own project?

Comment: I don't think there exist any alternative in javafx API as long as i know. so you can just go with the fxexperience.